# if array empty blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have this blade template and i wanna first check if the $dejeuner date exist if so do the rest else show a message but this line of code show both the error and fetch the details or if i change it i get only the error even though in else i ask to fetch data .can you guys check for me

```
   <div style="text-align: center;" id="lunch">
    @if(emptyArray($dejeuner))
        <h2 class="sessiontitle">Déjeuner : </h2>
        <ul style=" text-align: center;margin-top: 10%">
            <li class="menuitems">menu non disponible</li>
        </ul>

    @else
        <h2 class="sessiontitle">Déjeuner : {{$dejeuner[0]->date}}</h2>


    @foreach($dejeuner as $dej)
        <ul style=" text-align: center;margin-top: 10%">
            @foreach($dej->liste as $list)

                <li class="menuitems">{{$list->plat->titre}}</li>

            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach 
    @endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align: center;" id="lunch">
@if(count($dejeuner))
    <h2 class="sessiontitle">Déjeuner : </h2>
    <ul style=" text-align: center;margin-top: 10%">
        <li class="menuitems">menu non disponible</li>
    </ul>

@else
    <h2 class="sessiontitle">Déjeuner : {{$dejeuner[0]->date}}</h2>


    @foreach($dejeuner as $dej)
        <ul style=" text-align: center;margin-top: 10%">
            @foreach($dej->liste as $list)

                <li class="menuitems">{{$list->plat->titre}}</li>

            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you it works great(i just had to switch what in the if to what in the Else but overall thank you so count is better than emptyarray or blade doesn't just like emptyarray

Comment: For what it's worth, there's no such function as `emptyArray` unless you built something custom yourself. Are you thinking of [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?